# Recover NTFS filesystem after DISKPART CLEAN

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery, filesystems, diskpart

I managed to run the `CLEAN` command in DISKPART on the wrong disk (disk 1 instead of disk 3 in `LIST DISK`). Now it shows up as a "Healthy (Primary Partition)". If I assign a drive letter to the partition Windows just tells me its not formatted.

I'm guessing the damage is not too great. I could use R-Studio to recover the MFT-tables and get some files out. But its not optimal, will produce some false data and will take a long time. I'd like to just recover the drive and get on with my day.

Anyone have a clue how? Can I copy some initial bytes from a working NTFS-partiton? For example using `dd if=/dev/hda1 of=/dev/hda2 bs=512 count=1` in Linux.

Exactly what did `CLEAN`do to my partition? I know disk layouts/NTFS very well so more details = good. I don't mind HEX-editing the bootsector.

**EDIT:**

My disk has MBR.

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(WS.10).aspx : 
Removes any and all partition or volume formatting from the disk with focus. On master boot record (MBR) disks, only the MBR partitioning information and hidden sector information are overwritten. On GUID partition table (GPT) disks, the GPT partitioning information, including the Protective MBR, is overwritten; there is no hidden sector information.

Comment: Recovery tools are your only option now, pulling the relevant files. There's no practical way to restore the file system, the damage would be extensive at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebooted and reinstalled the operating system. Drive came back.

This was probably not related to the reinstall. Since only the MBR was cleared on a non-boot-disk I guess the damage was nothing. Windows just needed to re-read the information on disk.